# Datatable only retrieves the first column of my CSV file

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable

I have a CSV file and I would like to display the content of that file in a datagridview. I am using the `LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv` library to do so, here is my code :

```
Dim CSVPath As String = CSVLocation.Text

Dim dt As New DataTable

dim csvR As New CsvReader(New StreamReader(CSVPath), false)

dt.Load(csvR)                           

dataGridViewSection.DataSource=dt
```

Now my problem is that only the very first column of my CSV file is being read and displayed in the datagridview.

I figured out that the reason for that is that the very first row of my CSV file only contains 1 String, my headers are actually on the 3rd row of the file.

Here is what the CSV file looks like in NotePad :

```
ETABS
23,,,22,,,8,,,,,,13,,,5,,,,,77,,,,,,,,,6,,,,,,159,,,,,,,,,,,471
GridX,X(ft),,GridY,Y(ft),,GridGen,X1(ft),Y1(ft),X2(ft),Y2(ft),[...],Level
```

The first two rows contains data useful for the program (it includes item counts and such), but that do not require to be displayed.

Is there a way to discard those two first rows from the datatable,while still having access to that data in the background?

Edit: A workaround would be to fill each cell of the first row with a dot until we reach the last column, in order for the reader to notice that there is more than one column present,so the CSV file would look like this:

```
ETABS,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,.,[...],.
23,,,22,,,8,,,,,,13,,,5,,,,,77,,,,,,,,,6,,,,,,159,,,,,,,,,,,471,,,,,,,
GridX,X(ft),,GridY,Y(ft),,GridGen,X1(ft),Y1(ft),X2(ft),Y2(ft),[...],Level
```

but it's a very inelegant method.

Comment: Is that CsvReader class coming from CsvHelper library?

Comment: @Steve it comes from here : [A Fast CSV Reader](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). I've seen it mentioned  a few times on StackOverflow and it seems to be regarded as the easiest way to read a CSV file, so that's why I'm trying to use it

Comment: You can copy the input file to a temp file without the 2 header rows, then load the temp file.

Comment: Thanks @NoChance. I think this is probably the way to go, reading each line individually using `reader.ReadLine()` and then filtering what I want to keep or discard.
However my CSV file also contains entire blank rows (for legibility if a human was to open it with excel), so even then I would have issues. I think I have no choice but to rethink the structure of my CSV file directly, rather than trying to work around it. I will keep you updated! Thanks

Comment: Yes, also, Excel shows different type of data structures and stores it all in one palce...Datagrid expects very specific structure. There are components (not free I guess) that memics the spreadsheet interface for .NET developers such as Syncfusion and others.

Comment: [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) probably is better suited for this situation. You can skip blanklines and define rules to choose lines to skip.